# How to add photos taken from camera to a document template in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera, android-pdf-api

I am very new to android and I need to make an app which basically should add photos taken via the app camera to a template which contains header, some text, three images and its description.
I have no idea how to start this project. Can someone please guide me through?
The camera should take three photos, or select from library. and these three photos should be viewed in assigned imageView area. (like photo grid app)

In the end, user should be able to take a printout of this document directly, after saving it as pdf. (and be able to share the file via whats app and gmail).. how is this done?

I know this is a lot to ask. I don't want full syntax, will google it.. just need the steps/logic. I know how to add a camera and display the bitmap in a view, but how should i make the camera take three pictures and assign them in imageview 1, 2 and 3.

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Cto.png)

Comment: checkout this github library for the capturing and showing image https://github.com/NileshJarad/ImagePicker

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenario 
1. You will need a screen with 2 actions : Add Image and Generate Document 
2. Second screen will appear when add image will be pressed . Here you will have options : choose from camera or take picture .
3. When you wll press generate document you have to verify if the number of pictures is >= 3 . If not go again on choose picture screen otherwise show them in gridview /recicle view and let the user to select .

Use Shared Preference to save the paths of your photos so you can access them when you generate the file

Useful for pdf https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/pdf/PrintedPdfDocument.html

For gallery http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample